# How to disable "Keybindings for desktop switching" in Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, emacs

How to disable the shortcut keys for "Keybindings for desktop switching" for Lubuntu 20.04 as described in https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html?

I need to use some of the keys there in Emacs, but Lubuntu 20.04 seems to intercept those keys before they even reach Emacs.

Comment: Could you please give specific details about the key combinations you want to use but can't?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, I was looking at `Alt-Shift-<the arrow keys>`. But in general, I'd like to disable anything `Alt` except maybe `Alt-Tab`.

Comment: Sorry I've been hoping to get to this for nearly two days (since this was posted), but I wasn't able to again today and may not have time tomorrow...  There are two levels of how shortcuts are caught, and I'll provide https://phab.lubuntu.me/T59 hoping you'll find clues there on lubuntu's stack (lxqt & openbox being two layers; /etc/xdg/lxqt/globalkeyshortcuts.conf/globalkeyshortcuts.conf & /etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml).. I'm leaving this comment/link as I fear I won't have another chance until thursday (aest)